# What does `/profile` switch of Windows `runas` command exactly load?

Tags: windows, user-profiles, runas

The windows `runas` command has a `/profile` switch that per help message *specifies that the user's profile should be loaded*.

What does it exactly load? What is understood by *user's profile* in this case? Are these just environment variables that can be seen with the `set` command or is it something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [About User Profiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776892(v=vs.85).aspx):

> A user profile consists of the following elements:
>
> - A registry hive. The registry hive is the file NTuser.dat. The hive is loaded by the system at user logon, and it is mapped to the
>     HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry key. The user's registry hive maintains the
>     user's registry-based preferences and configuration.
> - A set of profile folders stored in the file system. User-profile files are stored in the Profiles directory, on a folder per-user
>     basis. The user-profile folder is a container for applications and
>     other system components to populate with sub-folders, and per-user
>     data such as documents and configuration files. Windows Explorer uses
>     the user-profile folders extensively for such items as the user's
>     Desktop, Start menu and Documents folder.

Pay your attention to *Local User Profiles* and *Roaming User Profiles* explanation referenced there.